# Comic book panel with at least three trained assassins in melee trying to kill each other, quips about deadly feet

Tags: story-identification, character-identification, episode-identification

I know... that sounds terribly generic. I was reading [Jab's reposting of Deathlok](http://www.echoesofthemultiverse.com/viewtopic.php?p=84828#p84828) and it brought back memories of reading a comic book in the 90s where some assassins were trying to price themselves to their employer by being the last man standing of their fight. I'm 90% sure it was Marvel (that's mostly what I could get my hands on), I think they were primarily in red, and in one panel, one (Deathlok?) claimed that they "know 97 ways to kill you with my feet alone" (or some other improbably high number) to which the other assassin (Deadpool?) quipped that most of them involve foot odor. I don't remember anything of the others involved, but I'm pretty sure there were at least three of them, lovingly depicted in improbably gymnastic fighting poses in the prior panels.

I don't remember who won, mainly that pair of quips. It might have been an *X-Men* strip. The guy my brother borrowed the comics from was big into them.

Comment: I don't have the comic but apparently Deathlok does meet Deadpool as well as Fantomex and Wolverine in Uncanny X-Force volume 1 # 5.

Comment: @raj Eyeh, but 2010 is a lot later than I would have read this...

Comment: Sorry, I should've read the part where you said "in the 90s" before commenting.

Comment: Are you sure it was Deathlok? I don't have a particular memory of this panel but I typically associate him with guns, whereas the similarly-sounding Batroc the Leaper might brag about killing with his feet and is frequently mocked.

Comment: @starpilotsix: No. It could be anyone, although my brain is on red outfits and cyborgs. :-p